# Кто-то в очках?

Tags: перевод, грамматика

Example: У него борода, усы и очки.

Would it be wrong to write: "У него борода, усы и в очках"?

Which one is most correct?

Comment: У него борода, усы, и дырка в очках

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is correct:

> У него борода, усы и очки.

This is not:

> У него борода, усы и в очках

But also you can say:

> У него борода, усы, и он в очках

How to remember: if you say `he has ...` (`У него [есть] ...`), use nominative case - `очки`. If you say `he wears ...` (`Он в ...`), use prepositional case - `очках`.

Comment: I like the last construction. Спасибо большое.

Comment: The case to be used with he has ... (У него [есть] ...) is not accusative. It's  nominative (that is, similar to a from that can be easy found in a dictionary).

Comment: @Manjusri Thanks, it was a stupid mistake. I really can't remember why I wrote "accusative".

Answer (score 1):

One has ... (У кого-то [есть] ...) requires a nominative (not accusative).

*в очках* here requires some more words. This wouldn't make the phrase more canonical, but at least it would not be so strange to a Russian ear.

That is, it would be also OK to say *У него борода, усы и лицо/глаза/взгляд/(сам)он в очках.*